# Graphs in questions - tikz

Tags: support

Is it possible to make graphs in questions using tikz? Or must I insert it as a picture? I wanted to ask a question about graph theory. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tikz does not (yet!) work.

You can compile the diagram into a pdf file, turn that into a png file (or another format), and embed *that* in a question.

In linux, I usually do this with

```
pdftops filename.pdf - | pstopnm | pnmtopng > filename.png
```

Comment: Maybe bug the MathJax people to support TikZ? :)

Comment: Doesn't `convert filename.pdf filename.png` work?

Comment: @lhf: you do get the PNG, indeed, but there was some reason —which I no longer remember,— which made me prefer the multistep thingie.

Comment: @Mariano: you mean besides needing Imagemagick installed? But if you have access to `pdftops`, you can also use `pdftoppm -png filename.pdf > filename.png` which belongs to the same software packages as `pdftops` (which would be the pdf library `poppler`). I can conceive, however, a good reason to chain `pdf2ps` (which belongs to `ghostscript`) and `pstopnm` and `pnmtopng` (which belong to `netpbm`) when neither `poppler` nor `imagemagick` are installed.